# Mapbox map doesn't work. Only a blue circle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I just downloaded Mapbox and I'm trying to get the World-Scale AR working. However, whenever I run it, I get no map. Just a blank screen with just a blue circle. I added the 4 layers (ARGameObject, Map, Path, Both) but I think it's not working or something.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be example scenes with ready to use prefabs. You can try them to see if core features are working, for first. Remember that you have to type your licence code somewhere.